# usage of mapreduce on mysql with nodejs

Tags: mysql, node.js, mapreduce

How to use `mapreduce` for `node.js` without first loading all data from MySQL to node.js?

I am using this: http://www.mapjs.org/

Comment: looking for the same thing, haven't found it yet. I may start an open-source project myself just to get this going :-)

Comment: can I join you with this?:P